# Why does Perl's quotemeta() function behave differently when under the debugger?

Tags: perl, debugging

I am bitten by this little inconsistent debugger behavior. The `quotemeta()` function seems to behave differently when invoke under `perl -d`

`$ perl -e 'print quotemeta("/a/b/c"),"\n"'`

Output is `\/a\/b\/c`, which is correct and as documented in `perldoc -f quotemeta`.

Now, when under debugger, the output becomes `\\/a\\/b\\/c`. I thought some core module I am using was redefining the function though as tested, it seems the behavior only occurs when under the debugger. Calling `CORE::quotemeta()` returns the same output.

Can somebody enlighten me?

Thanks!

Comment: "the output becomes"?  Are you saying print actually outputs something different?

Comment: "the output becomes" means output of the 'x' command, that is, as opposed to the 'p' command in the debugger.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`quotemeta` is a shotgun, escaping all non-word characters whether they need it or not. The debugger is less heavy-handed; quoting only those characters that need it. (Backslashes do, forward slashes do not.) More importantly, it only does this when you examine values, not when you print them. Compare:

```
  DB<1> x quotemeta('a/b/c')
0  'a\\/b\\/c'

  DB<2> p quotemeta('a/b/c')
a\/b\/c
```

Comment: I've been using the 'x' command since, thanks for pointing out the 'p' command

Answer (score 3):

I can't find a reference for this, but the perl debugger, when asked to output any string, will re-quote it so it's a safe literal value you could paste into a script. Your value is correct; it's the debugger that's adding the backslashes. There is a `quote` option in `perldoc perldebug`, you might try messing with that.